# TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not str How do I fix?

Tags: python, linux, pygame, raspberry-pi

I coded this from a youtbe video and he seemed to do it fine but when I tried I got the error message at the bottom I am so confused and I need help please.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygame, sys

from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((370, 572), 0, 32)

backgroundfile = "back.png"
mousefile = "mouse.png"

back = pygame.image.load(backgroundfile).convert()
mouse = pygame.image.load(mousefile).convert_alpha()

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    #Now we have initialized everything lets start with the main part

    screen.blit("back.png", (0,0))

    pygame.display.flip()
```

When I run the program I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tutorial 5 First game.py", line 26, in <module>
  screen.blit("back.png", (0,0))
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not str
```

I'm not sure what this means or how to fix

THIS WAS THE FIX

> You have two problems. Your first is that you put quotes around
>   `back.png`, making it into a string `(str)` instead of a surface
>   `(pygame.Surface)`. Your second is that you put a tuple for the second
>   argument instead of a rect `(pygame.Rect).` To fix the first, simply put
>   backgroundfile (what you previously saved the surface as) instead of
>   `"background.png"`. To fix the second, use `backgroudfile.get_rect()` to
>   get the background's rect. Your line should be:
>
> `screen.blit(backgroundfile, backgroundfile.get_rect()` This by itself
>   will not work because you didn't previously save backgroundfile as a
>   surface object. Instead of
>
> `backgroundfile = "back.png"` put
>
> `backgroundfile = pygame.image.load("back.png")` This will return a
>   surface, if `"back.png"` is saved as a file in the same folder. Do the
>   same thing with the other loaded image. Do all these things and your
>   program should work.

Comment: Hint: why do you go to the trouble of creating variables to store that filename, then creating images out of it, if you don't use those images? (Also please edit your post so that the indentation is correct. This is crucial for Python.)

Comment: @Mat this may be only a snippet of the program, as he may be using those images later (that's my guess :P).

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND: my guess is that `screen.blit` takes an image as an argument...

Comment: Based off of what Mat said, I don't think you should have `screen.blit("back.png", (0,0))`, but rather `screen.blit(back, (0,0))`, because you already initialized the variable `back` as an image you opened previously.

Comment: Thanks guys saved my life i have now got the pictue up :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two problems.  Your first is that you put quotes around `back.png`, making it into a string (str) instead of a surface (pygame.Surface).  Your second is that you put a tuple for the second argument instead of a rect (pygame.Rect).  To fix the first, simply put `backgroundfile` (what you previously saved the surface as) instead of `"background.png"`.  To fix the second, use `backgroudfile.get_rect()` to get the background's rect.  Your line should be:

```
screen.blit(backgroundfile, backgroundfile.get_rect()
```

This by itself will not work because you didn't previously save backgroundfile as a surface object.  Instead of

```
backgroundfile = "back.png"
```

put

```
backgroundfile = pygame.image.load("back.png")
```

This will return a surface, if "back.png" is saved as a file in the same folder.  Do the same thing with the other loaded image.  Do all these things and your program should work.