# I got the error " TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface " because I tried to share a value between 2 python codes using a .txt file

Tags: python, file, pygame

`print('Hello world!')` I am trying to control one pygame window using 2 different python files(`fish_simulator.py` and `settings.py`), so as follows, I have `fish_simuator.py` as the main file, which will execute `settings.py` if a certain thing happens, but I ran into a problem with sharing data between `fish simulator.py` and `settings.py` using a .txt file called storage_file.txt, so here is a bit of my program:

This is a part of `fish simulator.py`

```
pygame.init()
flags = RESIZABLE
size_of_monitor = pygame.display.Info()
width = size_of_monitor.current_w - 25
height = size_of_monitor.current_h - 50
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), flags)

#some code later

if result == 1:
    #open settings
    with open(r'files\storage_file.txt', 'w') as storage_file:
        storage_file.write(str(screen))
    exec(open(r'.\extra programs\settings.py').read())
```

This is a part of `settings.py`

```
#inside of the code that gets executed
import pygame, os, time, random, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

with open(r'files\storage_file.txt', 'r') as storage_file:
    screen = storage_file.read()

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (random.randint(1, 400), random.randint(1, 400), 10, 10))
pygame.display.update()
time.sleep(2)
```

In the main code everything is fine, `screen` gets created and then saved inside of `storage_file.txt` and then when `fish simulator` executes  `settings.py`, `settings.py` extract `screen` as a string, and when I try to run `pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (random.randint(1, 400), random.randint(1, 400), 10, 10))`, it gives me an error that says

```
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not str
```

so instead of `surface == <Surface(1234x123x12 SW)>` I got `surface == "<Surface(1234x123x12 SW)>"` from the `storage_file.txt`. And although it may seem dumb to some, but I was so desperate that I tried raw_input() and exec(), as I couldn't find anything else on this problem, and I also looked in these places, but its not what I need:

[TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not str How do I fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083566/typeerror-argument-1-must-be-pygame-surface-not-str-how-do-i-fix)

[TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not str [Pygame using buttons]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48050110/typeerror-argument-1-must-be-pygame-surface-not-str-pygame-using-buttons)

[TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33861791/typeerror-argument-1-must-be-pygame-surface-not-str)

https://cmsdk.com/python/python-typeerror-argument-1-must-be-pygame-surface-not-pygame-rect.html

https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/hsl0z6/windowblit_typeerror_argument_1_must_be/

Comment: What do you mean by *"because of a conversion from .txt to .py"*?

Comment: The issue is obvious. You use the variable `screen` twice. What do you expect by `screen = storage_file.read()`? `sceen` is the _Surface_ associated to the display. You have to use another name for the file.

Comment: You cannot save the `screen` _Surface_ as a text file. The display _Surface_ must be a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) generated by [`pygame.display.set_mode`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode). What do you expect by `storage_file.write(str(screen))`?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I meant that when I read the contents from the ```storage_file.txt```, inside of ```code.py```, I technically convert data from ```storage_file.txt``` into ```code.py```, sorry if this confused you, I don't know how to explain it properly

Comment: *"I technically convert data from storage_file.txt into code.py [...]"* - No you don't do anything like that. All you have done is to store the string representation of an a _Surface_ object.

Comment: Your question is still unclear. Do you want to store a screenshot or do you want to store the values of some variables? This are completely different things.

Comment: oh... but can I convert the string back into a surface object?

Comment: I want to store the value of the variable ```screen``` inside of ```fish simulator.py``` and transfer it into ```settings.py```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save the screen to a file, you need to convert it to numbers:

width is screen width
height is screen height

```
screen_array = pygame.surfarray.array3d(screen)

you then save the r, g, b values
with open("test1", "w") as a_file:  
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
           a_file.write(str(screen_array[x][y][0])
           a_file.write(" ")
           a_file.write(str(screen_array[x][y][1])
           a_file.write(" ")
           a_file.write(str(screen_array[x][y][2])
           a_file.write("\n")
```

and to write it back you reverse this process.

Surfarray requires numpy. I may have the array indices the wrong way round, so you might have to play with this a little.

To read them back in:

```
surf = pygame.Surface((width, height))
def load(self):
    x = y = 0
    
    with open("test1", "r") as a_file:
        for a_line in a_file:
            vals = a_line.split()
            r = int(vals[0])
            g = int(vals[1])
            b = int(vals[2])
            a = 255

            surf.set_at((x,y), (r,g,b,a))
            x += 1
            if x == self.width:
                y += 1
                x = 0
```

This will read the values back in and set them on the surface.

Comment: Woah, I am not currently home, but I will definitely try this, although I am a little bit confused. How exactly will I reverse the process? Do I need to use another command like surfarray or do I just pour the values from the file into a variable?

Comment: Thanks for the edit! The moment I will get home I will try it, but can you please tell me why you used self.surf instead of just surf? I am VERY new to classes and find it very hard to figure out how they work

Comment: Sorry, you only need self if the surf is part of a class, otherwise just use surf. I copied this from my own code and it used a class. 2 minute class tutorial: https://old.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/mt4zdo/object_oriented_programming/guxnjdq/